# Target element with non-empty attribute

Tags: css

I want to style my input field but somehow I have to detect if this input has placeholder attribute and if is actually filled. I would like to avoid JS stuff to do it, so my question is: Is there any css trick so i can target this specific selector?

Currently i have:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="">

input[placeholder] {
 // my styles
}
```

but this applies styles anyway. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [:not(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)) selector like

```css
[placeholder]:not([placeholder=""]) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="">

<input type="text" placeholder="test">
```

Comment: How the.. I didn't thought about :not() selector. Thank you sir :)